# Error posting a JSON object to nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to post the JSON object "updated" to nodeJS server....and save it to MongoDB using `.update`.

Javascript in front-end:

```
$(".save-changes").click( function () {
    var updated = $scope.users;
    $http.post("/update", updated);
});
```

Node.js:

```
app.post('/update', function (req, res) {
    MyUser.update( req.updated , function ( err, doc ) {
    err ? res.send( err ) : res.redirect( '/' );
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I used "req.body" instead of "req.updated".

Answer (score 0):

Try `req.body.updated` in `MyUser.update`.

```
app.post('/update', function (req, res) {
    MyUser.update( req.body.updated , function ( err, doc ) {
    err ? res.send( err ) : res.redirect( '/' );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead. "req.body.updated" did not work, however, "req.body" did.